# Delete folder for which every API call fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, delete-file, access-denied

I have created a folder with [`CreateDirectoryW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx) to which I haven't got access. I used `nullptr` as a security descriptor, but for some reason it didn't copy the parent folder's ACLs, but instead made the folder inaccessible.

I can't view or change the owner. [takeown](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024(v=ws.10).aspx), [icacls](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(v=ws.10).aspx), [`SetNamedSecurityInfoW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579(v=vs.85).aspx), all from elevated processes or command prompts, fail with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Do I have any chance of deleting this folder in Windows (Shell or C++) before trying a Linux live CD which hopefully doesn't care about the ACLs?

Comment: [`ZwDeleteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566435(v=vs.85).aspx) will be worked in your case

Comment: [Boot windows to a command prompt](http://www.wikihow.com/Boot-to-Command-Prompt) and see if you can delete it from there.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to enable backup (or restore) privilege:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t ** argv)
{
    // argv[1] must contain the directory to remove

    HANDLE hToken;
    struct 
    {    
        DWORD PrivilegeCount;
        LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privileges[1];    
    } tkp;

    if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), 
        TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken)) 
    {
        LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_BACKUP_NAME, &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid);

        tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

        if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, 
            (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)&tkp, 0, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0))
        {
            printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges: %u\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            // This happens if you don't have the privilege
            printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges: %u\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }

        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }

    if (!RemoveDirectory(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("RemoveDirectory: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in the interests of conciseness, some error handling has been omitted.  Also note that AdjustTokenPrivileges() is one of the few special cases where calling GetLastError() is meaningful even though the call succeeded; it will return `ERROR_SUCCESS` or `ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED` depending on whether you actually have all of the privileges you were attempting to enable.

This is a fairly general solution for bypassing security permissions on files.  It works for most API calls, although in some cases (most notably CreateFile) you must provide a special flag in order to make use of backup privilege.  As well as deleting files or removing directories that you don't have permission to, you can change attributes, change permissions, and even assign ownership to somebody else, which is not otherwise permitted.

Comment: and still single call `ZwDeleteFile` do the same task, because `DELETE` and `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES` this is special access for files. file systems grant `DELETE` if we have `FILE_DELETE_CHILD` on parent. (`FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY` on parent for `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES`  on child). and if folder have read-only attribute - we need first change file attributes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

assume that file not open with incompatible to delete share flags and no section on file.

for delete file enough 2 things - we have `FILE_DELETE_CHILD` on **parent** folder. and file is not read only. in this case call [`ZwDeleteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566435(v=vs.85).aspx) (but not [`DeleteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`RemoveDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365488(v=vs.85).aspx) - both this api will fail if file have empty *DACL*) is enough. in case file have read-only attribute - [`ZwDeleteFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566435(v=vs.85).aspx) fail with code `STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE`. in this case we need first remove read only. for this need open file with `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` access. we can do this if we have `SE_RESTORE_PRIVILEGE` and set `FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT` option in call to [`ZwOpenFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567011(v=vs.85).aspx). so code for delete file can be next:

```
NTSTATUS DeleteEx(POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES poa)
{
    NTSTATUS status = ZwDeleteFile(poa);

    if (status == STATUS_CANNOT_DELETE)
    {
        BOOLEAN b;
        RtlAdjustPrivilege(SE_RESTORE_PRIVILEGE, TRUE, FALSE, &b);
        HANDLE hFile;

        IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
        if (0 <= (status = NtOpenFile(&hFile, FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, poa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT)))
        {
            static FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION fbi = {{},{},{},{}, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL};
            status = ZwSetInformationFile(hFile, &iosb, &fbi, sizeof(fbi), FileBasicInformation);
            NtClose(hFile);

            if (0 <= status)
            {
                status = ZwDeleteFile(poa);
            }
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:winapi]. None of your calls are part of the Windows API. While this may solve the issue, it doesn't address the question that was asked.

Comment: @IInspectable - what I use also winapi - exported functions from some user mode dll (ntdll.dll in concrete case). no different between another user mode dlls. and all this api well documented. and if file initially not have read-only attribute - single call to `ZwDeleteFile` do task. or you have better solution ?

Comment: The published Windows API documentation is contractual. The published native API documentation is informational only. See [Calling Internal APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432200.aspx) for reference. When you have to provide support for your software, this makes a big difference. Professional software developers usually have to provide support for their software.

Comment: @IInspectable - *published native API documentation is informational only.* - this is why ? where in concrete documentation - say - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566435(v=vs.85).aspx this stated ? this is well known api. all documented at least ~20 years. and supported in both user and kernel mode. which is also documented. in what problem ? the `ZwDeleteFile` is the best solution. and this api have no kernel32 shell. so here no choice

Comment: @IInspectable My question specifically asked for "any chance to delete in Shell or C++", the tagging was not meant to specifically exclude NT API solutions.

Comment: @FelixDombek: There is a tag specifically for the NT native API ([tag:nt-native-api]). The tags on your question do preclude use of the NT native API. Besides, Stack Overflow isn't about *your* problem, or a solution that works only for you. It is a database of programming problems and solutions for *everyone*. This proposed answer does not address your question, as currently written.

Comment: @IInspectable by this logic, my tagging would also prevent someone from answering in plain ISO C++. Should I remove the `winapi` tag? The question is more useful if it welcomes answers that get the job done without worrying about the exact api, IMHO. (My, possibly wrong, assumption was that just tagging "C++" could be understood to mean that answers are restricted to ISO C++, which is not what I want.)

Comment: @FelixDombek: Tagging a question [tag:c++] does not preclude an answer using ISO C++ (not sure how anyone could arrive at that conclusion). Likewise, tagging a question [tag:winapi] does not preclude an answer using the Windows API (which was posted). Neither tag suggests, that use of an implementation detail (the Native API) can be used in an answer. While it may solve your immediate issue, it could just be useless to a future visitor, expecting an answer that addresses the question being asked.

Comment: @IInspectable APIs change, but the NT API isn't as volatile as you suggest. Yes, there is no real contract, but .. in reality it has be stable for decades. Anyway, I made [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357806/how-to-tag-c-windows-questions) to clarify how this question should be tagged.

Comment: @FelixDombek: Don't change your question after the fact. You have received an answer addressing the question that was asked (not this one). Besides, I'm not claiming, that the Native API were volatile. It's just not officially supported, and that matters to some (most?) developers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156684/discussion-between-felix-dombek-and-iinspectable).